# Is there difference between function,struct enum and struct property in template recursion?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, enums

I was finding how to use template to generate triangle number,at start I wrote something like:

```
template<int i>
int f(){
    return i+f<i-1>();
}

template <>
int f<1>(){
    return 1;
}

printf("%d\n",f<4>());
```

but later it seems did something wrong because I found it should be using enum to do that:

```
template<int i>
struct f{
    enum{v=i+f<i-1>::v};
};

template<>
struct f<1>{
    enum{v=1};
};

printf("%d\n",f<4>::v);
```

I guess using f<4>() only generates 1,2,3,4 at compile time but using f<4>::v really generates 10 at compile time, is that right?

besides that,are there any difference?

Also if I use class property instead of enum:

```
template<int i>
struct f{
public:
    int v=i+f<i-1>().v;
};

template<>
struct f<1>{
public:
    int v=1;
};
printf("%d\n",f<4>().v);
```

,is the case similar to using function?

Answer (score 0):

Result of your function `f` and `struct f` cannot be used in constant expressions, but result of your variant with enum can. For using in constant expression function should be
`constexpr int f()` and it's allowed only in C++11, struct should be

```
template<int i>
struct f{
public:
    static const int v= i + f<i-1>::v;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With optimizations enabled, all of these should compute `10` at compile-time.

The difference lies in what you can do with the resulting value. The function's return value is not a constant expression, so you can't use it where a constant expression is needed. An enum value, on the other hand, *is* a constant expression.

```
template <int> struct Foo {};

Foo<f<4>::v> f1; // OK
Foo<f<4>()> f2;  // Compile-time error
```

C++11 introduced (and C++14 buffed up) `constexpr` functions. They are functions that, given constant expressions as parameters, can return a constant expression. If you declare `f` as `template <int i> constexpr int f()`, the second `Foo` instanciation is well-formed.